# Getting a PC back up during the dying state

Tags: dnd-4e, healing

When a character enters the dying state (0 or below 0), what can you do during battle or after battle to get him back on his feet?

I've only read that he must roll savings throws each turn (3 below 10 means you die), and a natural 20 will get him back up. But I don't know of any other ways to get him up but the twenty roll.

Answer (score 10):

There are several things you can do. It is important to note that a dying character which heals any amount of hit points, will go to 0 hit points, and then gain that number of hit points. Therefore a person with -20 hit points who is healed for 10 will have 10 HP, not -10.

**Heal Checks** can do several things:

> **FIRST AID**
>   Make a Heal check to administer first aid to a subject.
>
> **Action:** Standard action. The subject must be adjacent to the creature performing first aid.
>
> **DC:** The DC depends on which of the following tasks the creature attempts.
>
> Grant Second Wind (DC 10): The subject can use its second wind, if available, without taking an action. The subject doesn’t gain the defense bonus normally granted by second wind, but still gains any other benefits associated with its second wind, such as a benefit granted by a class feature or a feat.
>
> Grant a Saving Throw (DC 15): The subject can either make a saving throw immediately or gain a +2 bonus to a saving throw at the end of its next turn.
>
> Stabilize the Dying (DC 15): If the subject is dying, the subject stops making death saving throws until it takes damage. Being stabilized does not change the subject’s current hit point total.  - Published in Player's Handbook, page(s) 185, Rules Compendium, page(s) 145. Retrieved via [Online Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/skill.aspx?id=9)

As always, **[healing potions](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx)** can be used. You need not be conscious to receive the effects of a healing potion. You also don't need healing surges to use some of them, like the potion of healing (linked above).

Furthermore, you can always have a leader use an **power** like [Inspiring Word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1590), which could make the hit points shoot up to positive numbers, helping that character get back to business. Once again, you need not be conscious for many of these powers to work.

Lastly, **[death saving throws](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=341)** can actually get you back up on your feet. You need only roll a 20 or higher on a death saving throw so you can spend a healing surge.

Comment: Huh, from what I'm understanding in your first point is: the dying character can use his/her second-wind on his/her turn while unconscious to get back up. Is that correct?

Comment: @user12482 No, another, conscious character can make a skill check with the Heal skill to allow the unconscious character to use their 2nd wind.

Comment: Would this count as a Minor or Standard Action?

Comment: Standard action

Comment: @pipperchip please don't link to dnd4e wikia. Its copyright infringement (there is no SRD or anything like that for 4e). I've changed all the links to the appropriate content on the online compendium.

Comment: In some possible irony, I think the original bullet points were better than the rules quote. The rules quote might not be fair use, and the bullet points just summarised all we needed fairly effectively anyway.